# COM+ application throwing permission error when run as specific user

Tags: service, com+, group-policy

I have a com+ application that when I connect to the machine and start the application, it works without issue. It is set with a run identity that is a service account with a non-expiring password.

I have another application (running as a service) that calls the COM+ application is set to run as the same service account. When I invoke the commands I need while logged in to machine that is running the service (the one that calls the COM+ application) it works without issue.

If I log out of the machine running the service and monitor the process that is running, I get the following error:

> The server process could not be started because the configured identity is incorrect. Check the username and password.

I'm trying to find out if there is a group policy that might be interfering here. Everything works fine when I'm logged in, but when I log out, the service continues to run but fails to call the COM+ application. I know there are AD policies that prevent services from running when the account is not logged in, but are there any that would prevent the COM+ application from starting when called from a service that is running as a user that is not logged in?

Any suggestions would be very helpful.

Comment: Your suspicion of it possibly being related to Local and/or other policies might be worth investigating (e.g. - LogOn as a batch, service, etc.)

Comment: I've already looked at the local policy and the logon as a service and as a batch job are already set with the service account. I think it might be a more global policy (which I don't have access to the DC to check) that is overriding the local policy. I'm not great with AD or permission stuff so I'm hoping to narrow down what I'm actually looking for.. I was going to try to use the %windir%\PolicyDefinitions and start sifting through but there are so many permissions to search...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue only showed up when the application was running as a service and the service account was not logged in. The issue I think was related to a double hop but where I'm not exactly sure. I was able to work around the issue by changing the identify for the DCOM object to use the specific service account's credentials.